# How to distinguish between clock stretching and MSB in I2C EFR32FG14

Tags: embedded

In diagram shown bellow of si7021 we have clock stretching phase and MSB phase,
I know we have a flag register I2C_IF ,but how do I see when one ends ant the other starts?

How do I distinguish between the two?
Thanks.
https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/efr32xg14-rm.pdf

https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si7021-A20.pdf
[image]

[image]

Comment: During clock stretching, SCL is pulled & held low by the slave device until it's ready. The master sees that SCL is being pulled low, and waits until the slave is ready (releases SCL) before continuing with clocking the MSB.

Comment: Ok so if i want to distiguish between the two.

Comment: @brhans, that's how it's done in I2C in general, but OP is instead asking how to do it using this MCU's registers.

Comment: Ok so if i want to distiguish between the two.
I need to use BUSHOLD flag to wait when it retuns to be 0.
and the collect the recieved data in I2C_RXDATA .
Is it correct so far?
What flag to use to sense when the recieving of the data is over?

Comment: Im confused by what you're actually trying to do. Why do you want to know when there's a clock stretch happening? What received data are you expecting to see in I2C_RXDATA? There is no data transferred during a clock stretch. Only after both the clock stretch and the 'MS Byte' are transferred will there be data in I2C_RXDATA, and that will be indicated by the RXFULL flag.

Comment: We have 3 stages _clock streching,MSBYTE,RXBYTE
i will use bushold to sense when its over.
with what flag to sense that MSbyte sending is over?

Comment: 'MSbyte' or do you mean MS bit?

Comment: In the diagram Its MSbyte and LSbyte

Answer (score 2):

The hardware takes care of receiving a byte with clock stretching - you won't get an interrupt until the complete byte has been received. The clock stretching is transparent to the software.

If there has been an error such as Clock Low Timeout you will receive the appropriate interrupt to indicate the error. You may need to institute a recovery mechanism to get the buss working again in such an instance.

An I2C bus can get locked up if a slave pulls the clock low permanently; the usual recovery by sending 9 clock pulses won't work in such instances.

SMBus added a couple of features including timeouts at the slaves to avoid the problems. In a system without such capability it may be necessary to power-cycle the offending slaves. Some designers do add that capability.

I'm unable to find anywhere in the manual regarding the mechanism of the support for clock-stretching in the reference manual for the EFR32 other than a statement that it is supported (Section 17.3.1.5). The state machine descriptions (section 17.3.7.1) are at the byte level not the bit level.

A question on the support section had the reply "...our EFR32 I2C clock stretching is mandatory, not an option.  EFR32 I2C master support  clock stretching by hardware, no need additional config."

[Answer to question re clock-stretching](https://www.silabs.com/community/wireless/proprietary/forum.topic.html/clock_streching_commandapi-Pezy)